# Getting noise while tryin to stream song to android over tcp

Tags: java, android, tcp, stream, noise

I've made some java code which connects and sends data to my android device over LAN, at the receiver side, the app uses AudioTrack to play the audio.

It seems to be streaming the audio, but the receiver plays back only noise!

Here is my sender code:

MainActivity has the following function -

```
public void startStream() {

    //initiate the audioTrack and play it, then start listening
    try {
        int minBufferSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(44100,AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO,AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);


        audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,44100, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, minBufferSize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

        audioTrack.play();


        Streamer streamer = new Streamer(MainActivity.this);
        streamer.execute();

    }catch(Exception e) {
        say("mainSuperException");
    }
}
```

This is the Streamer class:

```
public class Streamer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

MainActivity mainActivity = null;
int i = 0;
Streamer(MainActivity m)
{
    mainActivity = m;
}

protected Void doInBackground(Void... p) {
    try {

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(3210);
        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
        DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        i = 0;
        byte[] size = new byte[4];
        input.read(size,0,4);
        int s = ByteBuffer.wrap(size).getInt();
        //Start streaming the file
        while (i<s) {

            try {
                input.read(buffer,0,1024);
                ++i;
                mainActivity.audioTrack.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);

                Log.d("packetTag", "got "+i);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                mainActivity.say("InnerioException");
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                Log.e("packetTag", e.toString());
                mainActivity.say("InnerIllegalStateException");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("InnerSuperException", e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
                mainActivity.say("InnerSuperException");
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException io) {
        Log.e("ioexception", io.toString());
        mainActivity.say("OuterioException");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("SuperException", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
        mainActivity.say("OuterSuperException");
    }
    return null;
}

}
```

And for the sender I used the following Java code:

```
public class mainClassSend {

public static void main(String[] s)
{
    try {
        InputStream songInputStream = new FileInputStream("D:\\song.mp3");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        InetAddress group = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.2.8");
        Socket socket = new Socket(group,3210);
        int i=0;

        byte[] size = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(3359).array();
        socket.getOutputStream().write(size);


        //Start streaming the file
        while ((songInputStream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) > -1) {

            try {
                socket.getOutputStream().write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                ++i;
                System.out.println(i);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        songInputStream.close();
        socket.close();
        System.out.println(i);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Right now I'm just desperately trying to get this to work, so I've filled in all the values explicitly, even figured out the exact number of frames it sends, and sent that as the size.

It receives the size correctly, and keeps looping till that value, but all I hear is static.

I've looked all over stackOverflow, and tried looking into a lot of java class documentations, can't seem to figure out whats wrong here.